# Search Engine Database (Cassandra) & Best Practise

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, search-engine, cassandra-2.0

I'm currently storing rankings in MongoDB (+ nodejs as API) . It's now  at 10 million records, so it's okay for now but the dataset will be growing drastically in the near future.

At this point I see two options:

1. MongoDB Sharding
2. Change Database

The queries performed on the database will **not** be text searches, but for example:

1. domain, keyword, language, start date, end date
2. keyword, language, start date, end date

A rank contains a:
 1. domain
 2. url
 3. keyword
 4. keyword language
 5. position
 6. date (unix)

Requirement is to be able to query and analyze the data without caching. For example get all data for domain x, between dates y, z and analyze the data.

I'm noticing a perfomance decrease lately and I'm looking into other databases. The one that seems to fit the job best is Cassandra, I did some testing and it looked promising, performance is good. Using Amazon EC2 + Cassandra seems a good solution, since it's easilly scalable.

Since I'm no expert on Cassandra I would like to know if Cassandra is the way to go. Secondly, what would be the best practice / database model.

Make a collection for (simplified):

- domains (domain_id, name)
- keywords (keyword_id, name, language)
- rank (domain_id, keyword_id, position, url, unix)

Or put all in one row:

- domain, keyword, language, position, url, unix

Any tips, insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra relies heavily on query driven modelling. It's very restrictive in how you can query, but it is possible to fit an awful lot of requirements within those capabilities. For any large scale database, knowing your queries is important, but in terms of cassandra, it's almost vital.

Cassandra has the notion of primary keys. Each primary key consists of one or more keys (read columns). The first column (which may be a composite) is referred to as the partition key. Cassandra keeps all "rows" for a partition in the same place (on disk, in mem, etc.), and a partition is the unit of replication, etc.

Additional keys in the primary key are called clustering keys. Data within a partition are ordered according to successive clustering keys. For instance, if your primary key is (a, b, c, d) then data will be partitioned by hashing a, and within a partition, data will be ordered by b, c and d.

For efficient querying, you must hit one (or very few) partitions. So your query must have a partition key. This MUST be exact equality (no starts with, contains, etc.). Then you need to filter down to your targets. This can get interesting too:

Your query can specify exact equality conditions for successive clustering keys, and a range (or equality) for the last key in your query. So, in the previous example, this is allowed:

select * from tbl where a=a1 and b=b1 and c > c1;

This is not:

select * from tbl where a=a1 and b>20 and c=c1;

[You can use allow filtering for this]

or

select * from tbl where a=a1 and c > 20;

Once you understand the data storage model, this makes sense. One of the reason cassandra is so fast for queries is that it pin points data in a range and splats it out. If it needed to do pick and choose, it'd be slower. You can always grab data and filter client side.

You can also have secondary indexes on columns. These would allow you to filter on exact equality on non-key columns. Be warned, never use a query with a secondary index without specifying a partition key. You'll be doing a cluster query which will time out in real usage. (The exception is if you're using Spark and locality is being honoured, but that's a different thing altogether).

In general, it's good to limit partition sizes to less than a 100mb or at most a few hundred meg. Any larger, you'll have problems. Usually, a need for larger partitions suggests a bad data model.

Quite often, you'll need to denormalise data into multiple tables to satisfy all your queries in a fast manner. If your model allows you to query for all your needs with the fewest possible tables, that's a really good model. Often that might not be possible though, and denormalisation will be necessary. For your question, the answer to whether or not all of it goes in one row depends on whether you can still query it and keep partition sizes less than 100 meg or not if everything is in one row.

For OLTP, cassandra will be awesome IF you can build the data model that works the way Cassandra does. Quite often OLAP requirements won't be satisfied by this. The current tool of choice for OLAP with Cassandra data is the DataStax Spark connector + Apache Spark. It's quite simple to use, and is really powerful.

That's quite a brain dump. But it should give you some idea of the things you might need to learn if you intend to use Cassandra for a real world project. I'm not trying to put you off Cassandra or anything. It's an awesome data store. But you have to learn what it's doing to harness its power. It works very different to Mongo, and you should expect a mindshift when switching. It's most definitely NOT like switching from mysql to sql server.

Comment: A very solid answer.  Although I make a point to never say the phrase "You can use allow filtering," this is still very well done.

Comment: Yeah...there are SO many preconditions before I'd allow myself to "allow filtering" that I should probably take a "never" stance too :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. especially for explaining how Cassandra's querying works. The modelling is clearly the key. I'll try to get the model right and hopefully test it.